# How to return a class in a function with C++?

Tags: c++, return, getter, getter-setter

Im using `SFML` and I want to return something I identify to be a class. So I want to get  the payload and return it.  How do I go about doing that when `payload` is a class ?

```
sf::Packet payload;
```

How do I return this?

```
/**
* Gets the payload.
*/
int LoginPacket::getPayload() {
    return payload;
}
```

Every way I try I just get errors.  Do I have to use pointers?  Is it just because payload is being identified as a class and the compiler is telling me there's no way to convert it to an `int`?  So how do I convert it or what do I do?

Answer (score 3):

What do you want the function to return? If you want it to return an int, what does this int mean? Is it a field in the packet you want to retrieve? If you want to return the whole packet, you can do this.

```
sf::Packet& LoginPacket::getPayload()
{
    return payload;
}
```

The caller of the function can edit the payload, or make a copy of it, if they want to. You can make it read-only by adding const

```
const sf::Packet& LoginPacket::getPayload() const
{
    return payload;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what a function declaration is in c++.

[return type] [function name] (arguments);

You are telling the compiler that when it evaluates the expressions inside the function, it will return what you determine for the [return type].

In your function, you are telling the compiler to expect an int, and then you are giving it a sf::Packet.

If you want to return a class, then you need to set that class as the return type for the function:

```
    sf::Packet LoginPacket::getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
```

Now, this would be sending a copy of payload, so as Neil has shown, if you want to return a reference to the packet (so that we can use the same packet without needlessly copying it) then you would want to use his function:

```
    sf::Packet& LoginPacket::getPayload() {
       return payload;
    }
```

If you want to return a member of the sf::Packet, you would need to set the return type to that member, then do return payload.member;